# Let $y_1,...,y_k$ be the roots of $q$. Why is $q(x)\prod_{i=1}^n(x-y_i)$ only positive or only negative.

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I'm trying to understand this exercise:
[image]

Well, my teacher told me that I need to suppose $q$ has $k<n$ different roots in $(a,b)$. So we have the roots $y_1,...,y_k$ of $q$. Then if I set $p(x)= \prod_{i=1}^n(x-y_i)$, then I should get that $pq$ is an function with only positive values or only negative values at $(a,b)$. But I don't see this last step. Why is this true ?

Answer (score 1):

The product $pq$ is a polynomial with roots $y_1,\,\dotsc,\, y_k$ in $(a,b)$ and no others. Since each factor $x-y_i$ occurs as many times in $p$ as it occurs in $q$ (if the roots are all distinct, exactly once, but it also works if $q$ has repeated roots, if they are listed according to their multiplicity), it occurs in $pq$ with an even power. That means the sign of $pq$ to both sides of the root is the same. By the intermediate value theorem, if $pq$ had values of opposite signs, it would necessarily have a zero where it changes sign.

Comment: I understand your answer if it is true that I can write $q(x) = C \prod_{i=1}^n (x-y_i)$. I think this is true, but just checking.

Comment: $q$ could have roots outside $(a,b)$, but that doesn't change things. Only the roots in $(a,b)$ are of interest here.